# Is there a connector that breaks the default circuit when a plug is connected? (e.g. cut off speaker when headphones are connected)

Tags: audio, plug

I want the normal path from a sound card to go to a speaker/internal mic, but when a headphones or mic (mic with PTT, hence 4-pole) is connected in a 3.5mm plug then I want to reroute there.

Ideally I want this for 3-pole and 4-pole 3.5mm through-hole PCB mount.

I think what I want is TRS and TRRS switched socket. But they seem to only have one path broken when a plug is inserted. Should I use relays to switch the 2-3 signal paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrated switches are the easiest and most common way of switching off other audio paths.  You can find 48 examples [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-audio-connectors/434?FV=-8%7C434%2C69%7C411921%2C541%7C411888%2C541%7C416767%2C575%7C408395%2C575%7C408396%2C1954%7C175525%2C1989%7C0&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=50).

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find any TRRS that switch off all three non-ground, but now that I think about it for my application that's actually fine.